# Remove IAM OIDC identity provider from my cluster

Tags: openid-connect, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, eksctl

I would like to know how can I disassociate an OIDC identity provider from a running cluster. Put in other terms, how can I revert the changes made by this command

```sh
$ eksctl utils associate-iam-oidc-provider --cluster cluster_name --approve
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in eksctl right now, you can raise one github issue to ask for the same.

For the time being, please use aws cli iam [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/delete-open-id-connect-provider.html) to remove oidc provider